# Django ModelForm widgets not modifying on the page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to style Django forms, but widgets are not taking any effect.

My code:
forms.py

```
class bidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=bid
        fields = ['bid']
        widgets = {
        'place a bid': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
            'class': "form-control",
            'style': 'font-size: xx-large',
            'placeholder': 'place a bid', })
            
        }
```

models.py

```
class bid(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey('listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='listing')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, null=True, decimal_places=2,)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bid}, {self.listing}, {self.user}"
```

What is the reason it's not working? Answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What field is `'place a bid'` supposed to be?... You don't have any such field in your model (not to mention that would be an invalid variable name). Did you mean to write _`'bid'`_?

Comment: Yes, indeed! I meat 'bid'. I'm still a beginner so I make a lot of mistakes. Thank you!